# Excel 2013 Max Column

Tags: excel

Excel 2013 is supposed to allow for a maximum of 16,384 columns.

Yet, I cannot seem to get past the old 256 limit.

Am I missing something?

I have chatted online with Microsoft and they insist that the limit is 256. However, we verified several places that the worksheet limit is supposed to be more than 16,000.

Comment: This question does not belong on this SE site. Stack Overflow is for programming questions; you may be able to find an answer on super user: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are not in 'Compatibility Mode' by looking at the top bar of your Excel Window. The file name will say [Compatibility Mode] next to it at the very top.

[image]

---

If you opened an old file and haven't converted it then the old limits will still be present.  Do a Save-As and select the new format.

Also, if your excel save settings are set to an older file format then any new sheet you create will implement the same limitations.

[image]